# Converting QXmlItem to QtDomElement or similar?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qtxml

I'm parsing a fairly complicated XML file of the following structure:

```
<root>
   ... 
   ...
   <item> 
      <subitem id="1"/>
      <text>
         text1
      </text>
   </item>
   <item>
      <subitem id="2"/>
      <text>
         text2
      </text>   
   </item>
      ...
   <item>
      ...
   </item>
   ...
</root>
```

It's pretty crude but you get my drift I hope. I'm primarily interested in "item" nodes. So I wrote the following code (directly out of the Qt's online manual):

```
QXmlQuery query;
query.setQuery("//item/");

QXmlResultItems result;
query.evaluateTo(&result);

QXmlItem item(result.next());
while (!item.isNull()) 
{
  if (item.isNode())
  {
      // WHAT DO I DO NOW?
  }
  item = result.next();
}
```

Now, QXmlItem appears to represent two concepts, a literal value (like a string) or a Node, (which is what item.isNode() is doing). Unfortunately, I can't grasp how to convert the QXmlItem to something that will query-able again. In particular from the example above I'd like to grab the "id" attribute, and the text element. Can I do this using the XQuery approach, or am I way off base here?

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use QXmlItem to modify the focus of your query. For example:

```
QXmlItem item(result.next());
while (!item.isNull()) 
{
  if (item.isNode())
  {
    query.setFocus(item);
    query.setQuery("./text/string()");
    QString text;
    query.evaluateTo(&text);
  }
  item = result.next();
}
```

will retrieve the `<text>` value of the `<item>`.

Comment: You're missing an 'item = result.next();' from the end of your while and evaluateTo requires the address of 'text' in the last line of your if.

Answer (score 2):

`QXmlQuery` is one crummy piece of Qt documentation, but i would say that you write your query to return the items that you actually want i.e. (this is an uneducated guess)

```
query.setQuery("//item/subitem | //item/text");
```

W3Schools has a [Tutorial on XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) that might help

Comment: Worth a try, I'll give it a go.

Comment: I noticed that when using the '|' operator, the resulting list isn't necessarily ordered according to the order in the query, but according to the order in the XML file. Is there another way to combine queries to get the result in a persistent order?